# how to make custom navigation tabs in angular2?

Tags: angular

Here, I want to create tabs using divTab and corresponding click on  divTab shows and hide its content at the below of tabs.By default,the first divTab is active and **its corresponding content below it are shown and others hidden.** Likewise, **on the click of each divTab their content should show below and others get hidden.**
**How to show their corresponding content on the click of tabs below?**

Note: The first divTab must have "active" backgroundColor and rest #777; while we click on the divTabs they become active.

I am new to angular2, so getting difficulty in angular2 way?

```
    app.component.ts
    --------------------
    tabsData = ['a', 'br', 'Sp', 'hh','ee'];

showmyContent(){
----                    //show my tab0Content,tab1content
}

        app.component.html
            --------------------------
            <div class="col-xs-12 rmpm tabsMenu" id="navBar">
                <div class="">
                    <div id="tab{{i}}" class="divTab" style="width:calc(100%/5);float:left;background:#777;" click="showmyContent()" *ngFor="let tab of tabsData;let i = index; let frst=first">
                        {{tab}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab0Content" style="display:block;">Tab0 Content</div>    
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab1Content" style="display:none;">Tab1 Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab2Content" tyle="display:none;">Tab2 Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab3Content" style="display:none;">Tab3 Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab4Content" style="display:none;">Tab4 Content</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change backgroundcolor of divs when they are clicked in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819161/how-to-change-backgroundcolor-of-divs-when-they-are-clicked-in-angular2)

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373065/how-to-add-active-class-to-link-with-angular-2

Comment: Perhaps, question should be read again, there is a question regarding show and hide of its content on the click.

Comment: Start by accepting the answer you got on your previous question. If you understand it, the answer to this question is trivial (and basically the same): under the tabs, display the content associated to the selected tab: {{ selected.data }} for example.

Comment: @ManzerHashmi I agree it isn't a solution but don't try to repost your question. Just try to edit your old one. Check out my answer to and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use an *ngIf to toggle elements on and off.

```
 [...]
<div *ngIf="currentTab == 0" class="col-xs-12" id="tab0Content" style="display:block;">Tab0 Content</div>    
<div *ngIf="currentTab == 1" class="col-xs-12" id="tab1Content" style="display:none;">Tab1 Content</div>
[...]
```

And then you basically change that value `currentTab` in your corresponding component on clicking yout "tab".

There might be more sophisticated solutions but for a beginner this will certainly do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ngClass to your tabs.
Change your tabsData:

```
tabsData = [{name: 'a', color: true}, {name: 'br', color: false}, {name: 'Sp', color: false}];
```

And in the html:

```
<div id="tab{{i}}" class="divTab" click="showmyContent(i)" *ngFor="let tab of tabsData;let i = index; [ngClass]="{'buttonColor': tab.color}">
```

In your css:

```
.buttonColor{ 
  background-color: red; // play here with styling
}
```

Then last if clicked: **EDIT**

```
private showmyContent(_index: any){
  tabsData[_index].color = true;
  content[_index].show = true;
}
```

And now ngIf in your HTML:

```
<div id="content{{i}}" class="content" *ngFor="let content of content">
   <div *ngIf="content.show"> {{content.text}} <div>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to display corresponding content on the click of button.

Comment: @ManzerHashmi Is your content dynamic (change alot) or content stay the same?

Comment: content are dynamic and changes according to click of tabs.

Comment: So you have the content in a JSON? Like content[1] give json.result[1]?

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab0Content" style="display:block;">Tab0 Content</div>    
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab1Content" style="display:none;">Tab1 Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab2Content" tyle="display:none;">Tab2 Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab3Content" style="display:none;">Tab3 Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="tab4Content" style="display:none;">Tab4 Content</div>

Comment: These are tab contents respectively.

Comment: Need only the corresponding divs to show  on button click

Comment: your code is not working...can you give live example please

Comment: @Manzer I edited it a little bit remove the style=. style is replaced by `ButtonColor` Try to put your content (static) in a `this.content = []` array so you can loop over it. And play with your tabs.

This (ngclass) is an copy of my code it should work..